# Using awaits with fs.watch() in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fs

I have some code that talks connects to a redis and returns a promise like:

```
async connectionToRedisClient() {
    return await this.connect('connect')
    .then(() => {
        log.info('Connected');
    })
    .catch(() => log.error('Error connecting to redis'));
}
```

Which is later used to wait for a successful connection before proceeding with an algorithm:

```
await connectionToRedisClient()
```

This all works fine on its own, and has done for some time now - however, I am adding the `fs.watch` function to trigger this code when a new file appears in a directory.

The `fs.watch` code works fine, and attempts to execute the above code, but suddenly stops at the await and does not complete. My debugging leads to this code and only this code.

If I remove the redis code then the code completes fine. Is there a problem using awaits in `fs.watch`? or do I have some mix up with sync & async code here? Keep in mind that if I stop using `fs.watch`, the redis code is fine, so the problem isn't directly related to my redis code.

See my `fs.watch` code for reference:

```
fs.watch('./targets', async (event, filename) => {
    console.log('event is: ' + event);
    if (filename === 'file.txt') {
       await main();
    } else {
        console.log('Incorrect file passed');
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your error, but as far as I can see fs.watch plays fine with async. Do you have a minimum reproducible example, and also which version of node are you using?

Comment: I wonder if this is because you are using await redundantly in connectionToRedisClient(). Async functions implicitly return a promise, but that function is explicitly returning a promise, therefore I think there's no need to use async/await in connectionToRedisClient()

Comment: @MichaelHorn I am using v10.15.0 - I will try to append a minimum reproducible example to the question - I will try your suggestion also :)

Comment: @MichaelHorn Interestingly, when I remove both the await inside the function, and the one where it is called - the code executes fine as it should, but neither of the console logs inside the then() or catch() ever execute

Comment: You would still want to use await when you call connectionToRedisClient(), since that's how the returned promise is fulfilled in an async function. Does it work if both the async and await keywords are removed from the connectionToRedisClient() definition, but await is still used at the call site?

Comment: @MichaelHorn sorry for the delay in replying - I have tried what you have just mentioned but it does not work and does not execute